# Creating multiple JTables built from arrays doesn't quite work

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have written 2 class files that create 3 identical JTables in 3 BorderLayout areas: WEST, CENTER, and EAST.  The data they will display will be different, of course.  I want as much table definition code as possible to be in the 2nd file because there is more JTable function to come.

Currently, only the 3 JTable rowHeaders display.  There are no grids and no columnHeaders. The 1st file's class extends JFrame and calls the 2nd file's class 3 times. The 2nd file's class extends JTable.

I have another version of the code that creates one JTable from one class in one file, and it works perfectly.  The code in the two versions is as identical as I have found possible.

---

The calling class in the 1st file is "JTables3" --

```
public class JTables3 extends JFrame {
    static int tableCt = 3;
    static int WW = 0, CC = 1, EE = 2;
    static JTable[] jTable = new JTable[tableCt];
    static JScrollPane[] jSPane = new JScrollPane[tableCt];
    static JPanel[] jPanel = new JPanel[tableCt];

    protected void frameInit() {
        int i;
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_3Tables_wRowHdrs");
        setSize(750, 300); // window size, this works
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setupScrollPanes(); // a JScrollPane for each custom JTable
        setupPanels(); // a JPanel for each BorderLayout area 
        add(jPanel[WW], BorderLayout.WEST); // add West panel  to area WEST
        add(jPanel[CC], BorderLayout.CENTER); // *   Center    to      CENTER
        add(jPanel[EE], BorderLayout.EAST); // *   East        to      EAST 
        Sop("Added 3 jPanels to 3 BorderLayout areas\n");
    }

    public static void setupScrollPanes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableCt; i++) {
            jTable[i] = new JTab_forJTables3(); // get a new custom JTable  
            Sof2("Got jTable[%d] \n", i, i);
            jSPane[i] = new JScrollPane(jTable[i]); // create a new JSPane w/ JTable
            jSPane[i].setRowHeaderView(JTab_forJTables3.rowHeader); // REQ'D for row headers!
            jSPane[i].setColumnHeaderView(JTab_forJTables3.colHeader); // does anything?
            Sof2("Got jScrollPane[%d] with JTable[%d] \n", i, i);
            jSPane[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(190, 215)); // get 3 189x214 
            jSPane[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(190, 215)); // * rectangles
            jSPane[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 215));
        }
    }

    public static void setupPanels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableCt; i++) {
            jPanel[i] = new JPanel(); // create a new JPanel
            jPanel[i].add(jSPane[i]); // add its JSPane
            Sof2("Got jPanel[%d] with jSPane[%d]\n", i, i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTables3 frame = new JTables3();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void Sop(String output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void Sof2(String fmt, int nbr1, int nbr2) {
        System.out.format(fmt, nbr1, nbr2);
    }
}
```

---

The called class in the 2nd file is "JTab_forJTables3" --

```
class RowHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    RowHeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setForeground(header.getForeground());
        setBackground(header.getBackground());
        setFont(header.getFont());
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

public class JTab_forJTables3 extends JTable {
    static String rowHdrs[] = {"CL","v1","v2","v3","v4","TL","AN"};
    static String colHdrs[] = {"0","1","2","3","TL"};
    static int colWids[] = {16,16,16,16,30};
    static JList rowHeader;
    static JList colHeader;

    public JTab_forJTables3() { // constructor
        ListModel roMdl = new AbstractListModel() { // rowModel
            public int getSize() {
                return rowHdrs.length;
            }
            public String getElementAt(int index) {
                return rowHdrs[index];
            }
        };
        ListModel coMdl = new AbstractListModel() { // columnModel
            public int getSize() {
                return colHdrs.length;
            }
            public String getElementAt(int index) {
                return colHdrs[index];
            }
        };
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(colHdrs, roMdl.getSize());
        JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
        rowHeader = new JList(roMdl);
        rowHeader.setFixedCellWidth(25); // this works
        rowHeader.setFixedCellHeight(table.getRowHeight());
        rowHeader.setCellRenderer(new RowHeaderRenderer(table));
        colHeader = new JList(coMdl); // The column hdr widths match their
        //                                      // * column widths, as they should. 
        for (int i = 0; i < colHdrs.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMinWidth(colWids[i]);
            column.setMaxWidth(colWids[i]);
            column.setPreferredWidth(colWids[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help at all.

================================================

Thank you all for your quick responses!

Hello TT, my fundamental problem is that the 3 custom JTables do not display correctly, or not at all.  The double wrapping is looking forward to adding a JLabel title above each JTable.

Hello Andrew Thompson, maybe I don't need to extend JTable, but I do want to put my JTable building and (later) highlighting code in a separate file.  Can I do that without 'extends'?

Hello camickr, I really like your strategy.  Thank you.

Here is my simplest:  one JTable and one file.  It works fine: 5 cols, 7 rows.

```
public class JTable_1A extends JFrame {

    protected void frameInit() {
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_JTable_1A_");
        setSize(750, 300);                              // doesn't work?
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        JTable      jTable = new JTable(7, 5);          // create a JTable
        JScrollPane jSPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);   // *      a JSPane w/ this JTable
        add(jSPane, BorderLayout.WEST);                 // add jSPane to area WEST
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable_1A frame = new JTable_1A();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's my simplest two-file version.  It produces an empty window. 
File #1 --

```
public class JTable_1B extends JFrame {

    protected void frameInit() {
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_JTable_1B_");
        setSize(750, 300);                              // doesn't work?
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        JTable      jTable = new JTab_1B(7, 5);         // create a JTable
        JScrollPane jSPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);   // *      a JSPane w/ this JTable
        add(jSPane, BorderLayout.WEST);                 // add JSPane to area WEST
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable_1B frame = new JTable_1B();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And File #2 --

```
public class JTab_1B extends JTable {

    JTab_1B(int rows, int cols)  {
        JTable  jTab_1B = new JTable(rows, cols);
    }
}
```

Stepping through the code with Eclipse Debug, I noticed that jTab_1B is assigned id=45, and back in the main code, jTable is assigned id=44.  If it is the same JTable, wouldn't the id's be the same?

Thanks again, everyone!

================================================

How about a simple getJTable() method in another class in a second file?  Like File #1 --

```
public class JTable_1D extends JFrame {

    protected void frameInit() {
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_JTable_1B_");
        setSize(750, 300);                              // doesn't work?
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        JTable      jTable = JTab_1D.getJTable(7, 5);   // get a new JTable
        JScrollPane jSPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);   // *      a JSPane w/ this JTable
        add(jSPane, BorderLayout.WEST);                 // add JSPane to area WEST
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable_1D frame = new JTable_1D();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And File #2 --

```
public class JTab_1D {

    public static JTable getJTable(int rows, int cols) {
        return  new JTable(rows, cols);
    }
}
```

Works fine!  Five columns and 7 rows.
I think I need the 'static'?
Lesson:  Don't overthink the solution.
Thank you all very much.
   Key

Comment: Hello KeyLawson, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please [edit] your question and add a clear explanation of what is going wrong? I don't really understand your problem. Just browsing through your code, I have the following remark: add the JScrollPane instances directly to the panel with the BorderLayout, no need to wrap them in yet another panel.

Comment: `public class JTab_forJTables3 extends JTable {` ..wait, what? Or rather: ***Why?*** As in, why does this code **`extend`** a `JTable` when it could just use an instance of a standard table? Use a factory method to create a table if it makes sense, but don't extend components unless there is a clear requirement (e.g. custom painting a `JPanel`).

Comment: 1) get rid of all the static variables. 2) get rid of the custom renderer. That is first get the code working with the default classes, then and only then do you worry about custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Thompson may have solved my confusion. How about a simple getJTable() method in another class in a second file? Like File #1 --

```
public class JTable_1D extends JFrame {

    protected void frameInit() {
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_JTable_1B_");
        setSize(750, 300);                              // doesn't work?
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        JTable      jTable = JTab_1D.getJTable(7, 5);   // get a new JTable
        JScrollPane jSPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);   // *      a JSPane w/ this JTable
        add(jSPane, BorderLayout.WEST);                 // add JSPane to area WEST
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable_1D frame = new JTable_1D();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And File #2 --

```
public class JTab_1D {

    public static JTable getJTable(int rows, int cols) {
        return  new JTable(rows, cols);
    }
}
```

Works fine! Five columns and 7 rows.
I think I need the 'static'? 
Using camickr's excellent development strategy, it took me four iterations to get this working code.

Lesson: Don't overthink the solution. Thank you all very much. Key

================================================

BTW, I then tried custom code with arrays to get 3 copies of a JTable with rowHeaders,  and it worked, too.  File #1 --

```
public class JTable_1E  extends JFrame {

    static  int     tableCt = 3;                // nbr of JTables needed
    static  int     WW = 0, CC = 1, EE = 2;     

    static  JTable[]        jTable = new JTable[     tableCt];
    static  JScrollPane[]   jSPane = new JScrollPane[tableCt];

    protected void frameInit() {
        super.frameInit();
        setTitle("_JTable_1E_wRowHdrs");

        setupScrollPanes();                     // a JScrollPane for each custom JTable

        add(jSPane[WW], BorderLayout.WEST);     // add West jSPane to area WEST
        add(jSPane[CC], BorderLayout.CENTER);   // *   Center      to      CENTER
        add(jSPane[EE], BorderLayout.EAST);     // *   East        to      EAST 
        Sop("Added 3 jSPanes to 3 BorderLayout areas\n");
    }

    public static void setupScrollPanes() {
        for (int i = 0;  i < tableCt;  i++) {           // loop 3 times
            jTable[i] = JTab_1E.getJTable();            // get a new JTable     
            Sof2("Got jTable[%d] \n", i, i);            // log action

            jSPane[i] = new JScrollPane(jTable[i]);             // get a new JSPane
            jSPane[i].setRowHeaderView( JTab_1E.rowHeader);     // REQ'D for row headers!
            Sof2("Got jScrollPane[%d] with JTable[%d] \n", i, i);   // log action

            jSPane[i].setMinimumSize(  new Dimension(190, 215));    // get 3 190x214 px 
            jSPane[i].setMaximumSize(  new Dimension(190, 215));    // * rectangles each
            jSPane[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 215));    // * containing a JTable
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTable_1E frame = new JTable_1E();              // get JFrame w/ 3 JTables

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void Sop(String output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    public static void Sof2(String fmt, int nbr1, int nbr2) {
        System.out.format(fmt, nbr1, nbr2);
    }   
}
```

And File #2 --

```
class RowHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

    RowHeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setForeground(header.getForeground());
        setBackground(header.getBackground());
        setFont(header.getFont());
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

public class JTab_1E {                  // build & rtn a JTable w/ row headers

    public static JList rowHeader;                      // JList of row headers

    public static JTable getJTable() {                  // constructor

        String rowHdrs[] = { "CL", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "TL", "AN" };
        String colHdrs[] = {  "0",  "1",  "2",  "3", "TL"             };
        int    colWids[] = {   16,   16,   16,   16,   30             };

        ListModel rowM = new AbstractListModel()  {     // 'rowM' for rowModel
            public int    getSize()               { return  rowHdrs.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int index) { return  rowHdrs[index]; }
        };

        DefaultTableModel dTM = new DefaultTableModel(colHdrs, rowM.getSize());

        JTable jTable = new JTable(dTM);                // JTable w/ colHdrs & 7 rows

        rowHeader = new JList(rowM);                    // setup JList of rowHdrs
        rowHeader.setFixedCellWidth(25);                // this works
        rowHeader.setFixedCellHeight(jTable.getRowHeight());
        rowHeader.setCellRenderer(new RowHeaderRenderer(jTable));

        for (int i = 0;  i < colHdrs.length;  i++) {    // set individual col wids
            TableColumn column = jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMinWidth(      colWids[i]);
            column.setMaxWidth(      colWids[i]);
            column.setPreferredWidth(colWids[i]);
        }
        return  jTable;                 // rtn this new JTable with rowHdrs
    }
}
```

Thank you all once again!